# Como ocultar um Widget?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Preciso saber algum meio de que ao clicar em `Button` "ocultar" um widget (um `Label` por exemplo) de minha janela, sendo possível usá-lo posteriormente; Usando place no widget que desejo "ocultar" (Sim, PRECISA ser o `.place`).

**OBS:** Perdoem-me por alguma falha na criação da pergunta, ou falta de clareza; Qualquer dúvida que tenha sido por mim deixada, estou prontamente disposto a esclarecer por meio dos comentário.

**OBS:** Uso python 3, e para GUI: Tkinter(Caso não tenha deixado claro por meio da tag).

Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 2):

Olá!

Eu comecei a estudar o módulo `tkinter` ontem, infelizmente tenho essa mesma dúvida. Mas eu fiz aquela famosa 'gambiarra' rsrs:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

texto = Label(root, text = 'Exemplo')
texto.place(x=200, y=200)

root.geometry('400x400')
root.mainloop()
```

Aqui foi o código de exemplo, porém, quero "ocultar" a label "TEXTO".

```
from tkinter import *

def esconder():
    texto.place(x=3000, y=3000) #Faz a label ir pra um lugar que não aparece na tela


root = Tk()

texto = Label(root, text = 'Exemplo')
botao = Button(root, text = 'Esconder', command = esconder)

texto.place(x=200, y=200)
botao.place(x=200, y=350)


root.geometry('400x400')
root.mainloop()
```

Explicando o código, a `def esconder()` recebeu a "ordem" de jogar o `texto` para um lugar onde não aparece na tela, fazendo ele ser "oculto".

Caso você queira reutilizado no futuro, é só declarar o:

```
texto.place(x=200, y=200)
```

Que ele volta pra onde tava. Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Use o método **place_forget()**

```
from tkinter import *


def esconder():
    texto.place_forget()



root = Tk()

texto = Label(root, text = 'Exemplo')
texto.place(x=200, y=200)

bt = Button(root, text = 'Esconder', command = esconder)
bt.pack()


root.geometry('400x400')
root.mainloop()
```